# Connection to DB slow from Websphere

Tags: java, caching, websphere

I am using Websphere v8.5 (which hosts my java application) and DB2 as our database.

Previously while running the server in my local when my Databases were hosted in USA my application ran fast in my local. Now we moved our databases to France. So when I run my application on local it takes forever to load one page.

But when i use the same DB hosted in France to run queries through my Database client speed of the queries is same as they were in USA.

Could anyone please advice/provide any ideas on how I can configure any settings in my WebSphere to make it run faster.

P.S - I use dynacache in WebSphere as we have a lot of auto fill forms in the front end. Most of the getCache methods are the culprits here is wat I beleieve.

Comment: Sounds like you have an app that's too chatty that gets worse when the network latency increases.  I'd look at your queries and see if you can minimize traffic.

Comment: when both WAS and the DB are running in france, is the traffic going through some sort of proxy layer that is itself slow or geographically far away?

Comment: @AndyGuibert When both the WAS and DB are on the same server in France there is no latency issue. The speed of the response is fast as they are in the same location. The issue happens only when I run locally as I run from USA and the db's are in France.

Comment: @duffymo I cannot reduce traffic cause I need all the cache to auto populate dropdowns in the application without which certain pages wont load. Hence its difficult. I even tried saving the cache locally but still does not work.

Comment: I'm not understanding your question properly.  Are you looking for a way to make the DB <--> WAS connection faster?  When the DB and WAS are in different continents there is going to be latency, that's unavoidable... Caching will help but it will still take time to fill out the cache at first

Comment: Yes I am looking to make the DB-WAS connection faster reducing the latency. I am already using caching and thats the reason its actually taking up time to fill the first time cache. So was wondering why it happens if there is any way to make it faster?

Comment: Move your WAS where DB is, otherwise you would need major changes in your application as it looks like it is very heavy on DB. Such a long hop will introduce big latency on each query. You can actually use RequestMetrics to see how many queries you issue to build single page.